# problem displaying all percentages on bar chart seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I've written a function to plot a bar chart with percentages but I don't know why it doesn't display until `100%` and also it seems to display percentages as floating points. How can I display all percentages?

```
def bar_percentage_chart(x: list, y: list, xlabel: str):
    
    plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
    
    ax = sns.barplot(x=x, y=y, dodge=False, ec='k')
    
    texts = [str(int(i*100))+'%' for i in y]
    
    for i in range(len(x)):
        
        plt.text(i,y[i],texts[i], ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=15)
        
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
```

[image]

Comment: [`PercentFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter) has a *decimals* parameter.

Comment: By "display all percentages", do you mean changing the [`ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html)?

Comment: @BigBen yes exactly

Comment: Then read the `ylim` docs (link in the previous comment)?

Comment: thanks it's enough to set plt.ylim(0,1) and decimals = 0 in PercentFormatter. many thanks